# .htaccess redirect avatar's image folder to 404 custom page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Basically I am trying to **redirects** users from accessing the images/ folder of avatars in database directories from the url using .htaccess file for privacy concerns. The user should not be able to see other avatar's images

I've found on google on how to redirect user from accessing avatar's images folders to a custom 404 error page like for example

```
http://localhost/avatar/images/
```

to

```
http://localhost/404error
```

by putting this code in the .htaccess file

```
Redirect /avatar/images http://localhost/404error
```

it did redirected but the problem is that the page that includes/requires the images file from the folder **cannot** be opened. It shows like the image file is not valid but it did display the image before I put the redirect code in the .htaccess file.

What is the best way for me to redirect private folder to a custom 404 error page without preventing other page to display the images.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make it HTTP_REFERRER based (though keep in mind that REFERRER can be hacked).

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^avatar/images/.+ - [F,NC]
```

This will give Forbidden error to `/avatar/images/` URLs if accessed directly while allowing your site's pages to access them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont know why it doesn't seems to work for me. How exactly the HTTP_REFERER works? And how can I use it on my localhost machine.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is set by browsers when you click on any page of your website. Can you please explain `I dont know why it doesn't seems to work for me`

Comment: I've put the code but the images/ folder still can be access. how can i edit thi line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ [NC] ` to localhost/ ?